# SSRS - Using Conditional formatting (Background)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am new to Stackoverflow and I am fairly new to using SSRS and report builder. I am trying to change the background color based on values in 2 different cells, but it does not seem to work. I have tried using an Iif statement with a nested Switch statement, but this does not seem to work. I also tried using just a SWITCH statement, but that just gives me fields with no color at all.

What I am trying to achieve is that if the value in the "excav" column is "EX01", it must follow a different set of rules. Ways I have tried it:

```
=SWITCH(
    Fields![excav].value = "ex01" and Fields!tons.Value < 500 , "Red",
    Fields![excav].value = "ex01" and Fields!tons.Value >= 500 and Fields!tons.Value < 1000, "Yellow",
    Fields![excav].value = "ex01" and Fields!tons.Value >= 1000, "Green",
    Fields!tons.Value < 1840, "Red", 
    Fields!tons.Value  >= 1840 and Fields!tons.Value < 2300 , "yellow", 
    Fields!tons.Value >= 2300, "Green")
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPvXR.jpg)
In this instance, it completely ignores the conditions for "ex01"

```
=Iif(SWITCH(
        Fields!excav.value = "ex01" and Fields!tons.Value < 500 , "Red",
        Fields!excav.value = "ex01" and Fields!tons.Value >= 500 and Fields!tons.Value < 1000, "Yellow",
        Fields!excav.value = "ex01" and Fields!tons.Value >= 1000, "Green"),
        SWITCH(
        Fields!tons.Value < 1840, "Red", 
        Fields!tons.Value  >= 1840 and Fields!tons.Value < 2300 , "yellow", 
        Fields!tons.Value >= 2300, "Green"),"No Color")
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nv9Jc.jpg)
In this instance, it ignores all conditions and goes straight to the "No Color" condition.

Any Assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try do it by the textbox name( ReportItems!TextboxName.Value)

Comment: Usually there is no need to nest Iif and Switch. In your case I would prefer  using only Switch like you do in the first code expression. FYI: If you want something like Else in your Switch expression just use True as your final condition.

Comment: I have tried using it by the textbox name. It does not do any formatting now:

=SWITCH(Fields![excav1].value = "EX01" and Fields!tons.Value < 500 , "Red",
 Fields![excav1].value = "EX01" and Fields!tons.Value >= 500 and Fields!tons.Value < 1000, "Yellow",
 Fields![excav1].value = "EX01" and Fields!tons.Value >= 1000, "Green",
 Fields!tons.Value < 1840, "Red", 
 Fields!tons.Value  >= 1840 and Fields!tons.Value < 2300 , "yellow", 
 Fields!tons.Value >= 2300, "Green")

Answer (score 0):

Propably it has to do with case, which means string ex01 is different than EX01.

So you have to either change the expression to `Fields!excav.value = "EX01"` or use a function like LCase to make the values lowercase and then compare

```
LCase(Fields!excav.value) = "ex01"
```

I have added the sample image to show you that it works if you follow either of my suggestions.

[image]

On the upper table I use your expression, while on the lower table I have used the LCase function

```
=SWITCH(
    Lcase(Fields![excav].value) = "ex01" and Fields!tons.Value < 500 , "Red",
    Lcase(Fields![excav].value)  = "ex01" and Fields!tons.Value >= 500 and Fields!tons.Value < 1000, "Yellow",
    Lcase(Fields![excav].value)  = "ex01" and Fields!tons.Value >= 1000, "Green",
    Fields!tons.Value < 1840, "Red", 
    Fields!tons.Value  >= 1840 and Fields!tons.Value < 2300 , "yellow", 
    Fields!tons.Value >= 2300, "Green")
```

Comment: I also tried both upper and lower case, still does not do any formatting. If you remove the textbox name, it does the formatting, but ignores the formatting conditions for "ex01".

Comment: I tried the above code with the Lcase statement. It is still ignoring the conditions for "ex01". I also tried it with the textbox name: Lcase(Fields![excav1].value and with uper instead of lower case: Ucase(Fields![excav].value. All ended with either ignoring the "ex01" conditions, or with no formatting in the cases where I used the textbox name.

Comment: Don't use the textboxes name or value in your expressions. Your expression should be based (as it is) on the field values.

Comment: Ok, so this is how I have it at the moment:

<pre>    =SWITCH(
    Lcase(Fields![excav].value) = "ex01" and Fields!tons.Value < 500 , 
    "Red",
    Lcase(Fields![excav].value)  = "ex01" and Fields!tons.Value >= 500 
    and Fields!tons.Value < 1000, "Yellow",
    Lcase(Fields![excav].value)  = "ex01" and Fields!tons.Value >= 1000, 
    "Green",
    Fields!tons.Value < 1840, "Red", 
    Fields!tons.Value  >= 1840 and Fields!tons.Value < 2300 , "yellow", 
    Fields!tons.Value >= 2300, "Green")<code

And it is still ignoring the "ex01" conditions.

Comment: Any other suggestions? I am still having problems getting this to work.